# Can you decouple the Traveling Salesman Problem from the number of cities?

Tags: computational-complexity

I am studying the [euclidian version](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem#Euclidean_TSP) of the Travelling Sales Man problem:

> Given a list of cities and the distances between each pair of cities,
>   what is the shortest possible route that visits each city exactly once
>   and returns to the origin city, where the direct connection from city A
>   to city B is never farther than the route via intermediate city C.

And I wonder:

Is it possible to make the number of cities on the list have no influence on the average/estimated time it will take to find a solution? For example, to modify the rules that with 10 cities that you require 4 cities in the path, and with a million cities, that you require 400 cities in the path. So that each list will take about the same time to solve, no matter its length?

Comment: Do you really think that the number of cities would not affect the question? If you have a million cities, is it going to take the same time to solve as with $4$ cities? It seems like the case with $4$ cities is going to take at most $6$ computations, but the case with 1 million cities will take at least 1 million computations to show the result.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I explained myself wrongly. If I have a million cities its much easier to form a short path that hits 3 cities, then if I only have 4 cities to choose from. Because with a million cities 3 will likely be very to eachother, while those 4 could be very far apart in the world. So if it will be easier or harder depends on the retrictions. But is it possible to have restrictions where the number of cities dont matter?

Comment: That comment is nonsensical. If you have a million cities, you are trying visit a million cities, not three cities. Otherwise, you are not talking about the traveling salesman problem. @Muis

Comment: If you are talking about some other problem, please state that problem clearly *in your question.*

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I edited my question to do that.

Comment: You could always constrain the cities to be on a straight line

Comment: It's still not clear what that question is asking. Are you asking for a reformulation of the problem so that this is true?

Comment: @MarkBennet If you show me a formula how I can do that, I will accept it as answer.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I want to present people with the problem, and I want to make sure each peoples problem takes about the same amount of time to solve. But I have no influence on the number of cities each person gets, so I need to find a way to make it easier/harder depending on the cities. That way everybodys problem should be equally hard?

Comment: You should make the goal of your question clear. It sounded like a pure complexity question. Is there are minimum number of cities given? If so, and the minimum is $n$, have each person randommly select $n$ cities and try to solve it for that set. (If the minimum number of cities is $4$, this will always be a trivial problem, but that's because there is no way to make the $4$ case hard.)

Comment: The question seems reasonable to me, but it needs to be more carefully stated. Here is one possible formulation: We are given $n$ cities, and we have to visit $m$ of them. If $m$ is fixed, is there an algorithm that will find the shortest possible path in time that is polynomial in $n$? For this formulation, the answer is yes, because the total number of $m$-length paths is polynomial in $n$ if $m$ is fixed. But this is just one way of restating the problem.

Comment: As for whether the TSP complexity is exponential, that is unknown - the famous **P=NP** question is equivalent to the question of whether TSP can be solved in polynomial time or not.

Comment: He asked nothing about polynomial time, @TonyK.  He asked for *no* affect on the average time. He's asking for $O(f(m))$ time, in your example, for some $f$.

Comment: $@ThomasAndrews: Yes, you are of course right. I was trying to salvage something from the question, which I still think has potential.

Comment: Yes, but better to try to suss out what he is asking for, rather than projecting a possible meaning. There are lots of variants of TSP that are potentially interesting, but I can't figure out what OP is trying to say. @TonyK

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: That's why I suggested my own interpretation ("here is one possible formulation"). I don't think we have anything to disagree on here.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Im thinking about your solution to let each person pick X cities, where X > minimum. But I think people could cheat by not picking cities really random, and I have no way to find out if they did? Or am I overlooking something? Does that mean I always have to pick the cities for them? Or can you think of anything which would requires less central coordination, so that Im not required to give everybody a list?

Comment: @TonyK If you post your comment as answer, I can accept it. But please read my comment to Thomas to see if we are on the same page.

Comment: Wait, you want me to keep reading and responding to your long paragraph comments when you already have an answer you are ready to accept? @Muis

Comment: @Muis: I can't post my comment as an answer, because it's not an answer!

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Any solution to the problem I pose is fine, even if I cannot understand it fully. So if his comment is the solution, then yes I was ready to accept it.